# Insert statement in EF sometimes works sometimes does not

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a post method in one of my controller, which inserts some data in table. When I do some action that corresponds this post method on my web application, it shows response type as **200** but, unfortunately does not save any data in the table. I have a similar method which works fine and saves data in other table, but I have issue with this particular post method.

Also I'm checking for the following:

```
if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()>0)
            return true;
```

I'm really not getting the issue here.

Below is the function which inserts the data after validation:

```
 public async Task<bool> AddToCartInBulk(List<EcomCart> 
  ecomCarts,List<TableName> ecomHoldLots, string status)
    {
        // Below is the code which adds the record
        for( int i = 0 ;i < ecomCarts.Count; i++)
        {
            ecomCarts[i].Status = status;
            await _context.TableName.AddAsync(ecomCarts[i]);
        } 

        // this is for other reason(not relevant to the issue)
        if(ecomHoldLots.Count > 0 && status == "Approved"){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < ecomHoldLots.Count;i++)
        {
           _context.Remove(ecomHoldLots[i]);
        } 
        }
        if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync()>0)
            return true; 
        return false;
    }
```

And below is the post method code which calls the above insert function:

```
    .......
    ........
    var addtocartLotFromMapper = _mapper.Map<List<EcomCart>>(newList);
        var addtocartLotDone = await _repo.AddToCartInBulk(addtocartLotFromMapper, ecomHoldLots, AddToCartByUserDto[0].Status);
        return Ok();
```

**Note: This works perfect when I run locally.** Also there is a window service, which checks this table and records accordingly to some condition. I think this is blocking the insertion. But it used to work fine before.

Comment: It is hard to say without having more context. Is the caller code awaiting as well? It may be you await here it returns to a caller on await but here the call is not awaited and just keeps going.

Comment: show whole controller method if it's not too long (you can remove irrelevant code before pasting it here)..

Comment: Have you traced the code to see if everything before this line is executed as expected?

Comment: When I add a break point and debug it works fine what could be the reason?

Comment: Try the adding without the async. so just use `_context.TableName.Add(ecomCarts[i])`. If I remember correctly `AddAsync()` should only be used by special Data Generators.

Comment: Not sure if we see the full code, but what you posted does `return Ok();` *regardless of the value of `addtocartLotDone`* which would explain why you'd always get a `200 OK` response.

Comment: Ok Im adding the statment before last line  
            if(!addtocartLotDone) {
                    return BadRequest("Could not add to cart!");
            }

Comment: But this issue does not occur when I run the project locally

Comment: Are you logging exceptions? Is there anything interesting in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was that, there is a windows service running every 3 seconds which looks for the data in the table and updates it. I think it was somewhat locking it, I changed the time to 10 seconds. Thanks all of you for the suggestions.